# sqlite3 crashing with error EXC_BAD_ACEES(code=2,address=0*0

Tags: ios, sqlite

my code is

```
sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

    // Load all data from database to memory.
    BOOL prepareStatementResult = sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqlite3Database, query, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL);
    if(prepareStatementResult == SQLITE_OK) {
        // Check if the query is non-executable.
        if (!queryExecutable){
```

and i inserting data in the Student.sql database.my table having the  name Student.
my insert command is

```
NSString *query;
if (self.recordIDToEdit == -1) {


query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into Student values(null, %d, '%@', %d,'%@')", [self.MobNoTxt.text intValue], self.UniTxt.text, [self.YearTxt.text intValue],self.BranchTxt.text];

   }


[self.dbManager executeQuery:query];
if (self.dbManager.affectedRows != 0) {
    NSLog(@"Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = %d", self.dbManager.affectedRows);
}
else{
   NSLog(@"Could not execute the query.");
}
```

Comment: now this coding is fine, u need to verify create table method is correct or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if (self.recordIDToEdit == -1) line might be causing the issue as it might never get true and your are getting nil values for query. try changing condition or commenting it.